# Laravel Custom Pivot Model is missing fields

Tags: php, laravel-5, pivot, laravel-5.5

I am trying to use a custom Pivot Model like:

```
class A extends Model{
    public function b()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(B::class)
            ->using(PivotAB::class);
    }

class PivotAB extends Pivot{}
```

When accessing `PivotAB` through the relationship the additional field from the pivot table is missing (output from `artisan tinker`):

```
>>>$q = A::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1385
     all: [
       App\Models\A {#1386
         id: 1             
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $q[0]->b[0]->pivot;
=> App\Models\PivotAB {#1389
     a_id: 1,
     b_id: 1,
   }
>>> $q[0]->b[0]->pivot->custom_field;
=> null
```

But when i query the pivot model directly the field gets populated:

```
>>> PivotAB::all();    
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1382
     all: [
       App\Models\PivotAB{#281
         a_id: 1,
         b_id: 1,
         custom_field: "abc",
       },
     ],
   }
```

What am i missing? Do i need to declare the pivot fields somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add all fields to the relationship with `->withPivot('custom_field')`, so they get populated when querying via the relationship on A.

Somehow i understood the Laravel Docs as either having to use `->withPivot(...)` or `->using(...)`, but actually you need to include both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Sloothword ! I was suffering from the same incorrect assumption. 'withPivot', 'using', and 'as' all work perfectly well together. I ended up using the following successfully.

```
public function rosters(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Roster::class)
                ->withPivot('number','position')
                ->using(Membership::class)
                ->as("membership");
}
```